# How can we get the toxicity level of a plant without using animals?

Tags: toxicity

We need to know the answer for our research paper. We will appreciate it so much if you will answer our question.

Comment: Use people. Seriously though, this site is for asking specific questions about concepts of chemistry. You will need to take the short [tour] and read through the [help] to get a better understanding of how the site works. A good question will have some semblance of an answer, with a question or two about where you are getting stuck. We can't start your research paper for you :) Anyway, welcome to Chemistry.SE and best of luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to help write the OP’s research paper.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

You can't!

## Longer answer

1. Toxicity is not defined for a plant (or animal), but for specific compounds which are either produced or accumulated in these "toxic organisms". The concentration of toxic compounds may vary during the vegetation cycle and can depend, particularly in the case of accumulation, on the growth conditions.
2. Toxicity of particular compounds is typically given against specific endpoints, such as daphnids, rats, etc.
3. You asked for "the toxicity level". Which one do you mean?
   $\mathrm{LD_{50}}$, $\mathrm{LC_{50}}$, NOAEL/NOAEC, NOEL/NOEC, DNEL,...
4. If you cannot measure *in vivo* for whatever reasons, use established QSAR models for specific endpoints.